# Unable to start IIS with error :- cannot start service W3SVC on computer

Tags: windows, iis

I am bringing this question to stack overflow because I have literally tried all I can with searching but still haven't been able to fix this error.

How this all started this is when I had to give a restart to the IIS ,  so I stopped it manually and when I click start this error message keeps popping up

[image]

Another interesting this I noticed is that my application pools are no longer loading but a green color progress bar keeps going as shown below

[image]

Has any of you ever encountered anything similar to this ? if so would be great if you can share your experience

Also will re installing the IIS do any good ? and in doing so will my previously added application pool get deleted off ?

Comment: What did do before this issue happen and what steps have you tried ? Did you apply any update before?  What error message did you see when you use command"net start w3svc"? What error message did you see in event viewer?  Could you fix it by restart the server?

Comment: Corrupt Windows service is nothing abnormal. If you want to a quick fix, reinstall Windows or roll back to a previous backup. To troubleshoot the root cause though, is not easy and off-topic here as is not programming related. Common causes can be misconfiguration from either yourself or a recent installed software, or conflicts among applications.